# CKEDITOR add plugin to source view

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When using the find/replace plugin for ckeditor it is greyed out on the source view. To enable this I have found that you need to add:

```
modes: { wysiwyg:1, source:1 }
```

However, i wont lie, im pretty unsure where this should be placed.

It hopefully can be found in this link http://jsfiddle.net/SBmKz/ as it is 384 lines long.

I have tried researching this and have found a few examples of it in other plugins and also how it is done in the ckeditor.js  (n.modes={wysiwyg:1,source:1})  but cant seem to get it to work within this plugin.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Find/replace option is created to work on DOM, not on a plain text. That's why it is disabled in source mode. Actually, it would be a completely new feature the find/replace in source mode - especially if it had to omit tags.